# Info.plist configuration "(no name)" for UIWindowSceneSessionRoleApplication

Tags: ios, xcode, ios13

I am getting the below warning and the app shows a black screen for `iOS 13`

> [SceneConfiguration] `Info.plist` configuration "(no name)" for **UIWindowSceneSessionRoleApplication** contained UISceneDelegateClassName key, but could not load class with name **MyApp.SceneDelegate**.

**How can I resolve this issue?**

Comment: Would you please try to add this in AppDelegate `var window: UIWindow?`?

Comment: I have already added it but did not work.

Comment: So strange, I actually get the same error on Xcode 11.4.1 when I open a new project (single view, storyboard) and use an Umlaut (e.g. 'ü') in the app's name.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`SceneDelegate` has supported after iOS 13. If you want to use `SceneDelegate` and also want to support iOS prior to iOS 13 then you have to do some changes in your project.

Execute `SceneDelegate` if iOS 13 available.

## Code:

```
@available(iOS 13.0, *)

class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {
   //Other code
}


@available(iOS 13.0, *)
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {

}
```

## Add UIWindow object in AppDelegate.swift

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {    
    var window: UIWindow?
}
```

## For iOS 12 and earlier

> AppDelegate needs a UIWindow property. iOS 13 uses SceneDelegate in
>   new projects. Specify the `UIWindow` object and remove the
>   `SceneDelegate.swift` file.
>
> If you have removed the `SceneDelegate` from the project, then you must
>   remove the **Application Scene Manifest dictionary** from Info.plist.

Answer (score 10):

If there are no custom scene used other than Default one, remove 'UISceneClassName' from Info.plist.

```
<key>UISceneClassName</key>
<string></string>
```

Comment: This answer was my solution when trying to add UIKit to SwiftUI project in Xcode 13.2.1 https://mokacoding.com/blog/how-to-migrate-from-swiftui-to-uikit-life-cycle/

Answer (score 2):

Remove these lines in **Info.plist**:

```
<key>UISceneDelegateClassName</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).SceneDelegate</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

For some pure SwiftUI projects you could just delete everything under `Scene Configuration` in `Info.plist` to make it empty like on the screenshot
[image]